# How to implement this kind of style table

Tags: iphone, objective-c

[image]

There is table inside cell and every tiny cell can be clicked to trigger another page.

Comment: Try creating a custom cell which contains `UIButton`s

Comment: to be easy.One UITableViewCell with one UIImageView(two lines) and four labels(number) and four buttons(if the word is a link).:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like Twitter app.

I think, these methods may help you:

- Create a UIView with 2 Label for Number and Text; name it `labelView`
- Make a button `[UIButton alloc] buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom]`
- Add your `lableView` as a subview of this button.
- Make a cell with 2 button: side by side
- To make the seperator: `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`, then

  `labelView.layer.borderSize = 1;`

  `labelView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;`
- Manually move your buttons to appropriate position. You may want to use: `cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES` also

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSString* cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UIButton* tempBtn1;     
    UIButton* tempBtn2;     

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        tempBtn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        tempBtn1.tag = 123;
        tempBtn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 44);
        [tempBtn1 setTitle:@"firstBtn" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tempBtn1];

        tempBtn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        tempBtn2.tag = 234;
        tempBtn2.frame = CGRectMake(160, 0, 160, 44);
        [tempBtn2 setTitle:@"secondBtn" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tempBtn2];     
    }
    else {
        tempBtn1 = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:123];       
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tempBtn1];         
        tempBtn2 = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:234];       
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tempBtn2];     
    }

    return cell; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView subclass. This will represent one item (1/2 of the cell content). Add two of these in each cell. Detect touches in this UIView subclass and push new ViewController when you get the touch events.